# looking for good intro to probability book

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

Next year I will be teaching an upper level probability course.  The students will mostly be math education majors, and the course must have a statistics component. Besides the stats, I'd like to explore the more fun and theoretical side of probability (things like random walks or conditional probability paradoxes, for example) rather than doing a ton of integration with different distributions.   Does anyone have a good suggestion for a book for such a course?  Thanks!